# How do I dynamically generate link tags in header based on installed languages in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

For example, I have multiple languages installed and would like to dynamically generate the link tags. Preferably in my base.html's header.

```
            <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}{{ URL }}"/>
            <link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/da{{ URL }}" hreflang="da">
            <link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/de{{ URL }}" hreflang="de">
            <link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/en{{ URL }}" hreflang="en">
```

This is what I am currently using but would there be a way to do this by looping all the installed languages so I wouldn't need to update the HTML each time I add another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to  [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#get-available-languages) `get_available_languages` will return a list of tuples, where the first element in the tuple is the language code. We can loop over these tuples, and use the language code from each of them:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}

<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}{{ URL }}"/>
{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
    {% if lang[0] != LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/{{lang[0]}}{{ URL }}" hreflang="{{lang[0]}}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Notice we check that the language code isn't equal to your main one so you don't repeat that link.